# c # Автоматический скроллинг у класса Control

Tags: c#, winforms

Вывожу на форму данные с помощью textbox, использую следующий код:

```
private void SetText(Control ctrl, string text)
{
    if (InvokeRequired)
    {
        BeginInvoke((Action)(() => SetText(ctrl, text)));
        return;
    }
    ctrl.Text += text;
}
```

Когда включается вертикальный скроллинг, то всегда выводится список начиная с первой строки. Как фокус оставить на последней выведенной строке? appendtext не подходит, так как задача именно в этом методе это поправить.

Comment: если контрол является текстбоксом можешь попробова textBox.ScrollToCaret(); А то неясно даже что это за контрол в вопросе

Comment: он принимает текстбоксы, лейблы и ричбоксы. дело в том что нету у ctrl такого метода ScrollToCaret

Comment: `textBox.SelectionStart = textBox.Text.Length;` - установит курсор в конец

Comment: У класса `Control` нет такого свойства. Но у него в принципе нет понятия скролла.

Comment: Это WinForms? Добавьте метку.

Comment: Удалось разобраться?

Comment: @arc_pd потому что ты пытаешся вызвать этот метод у Control. А это метод текстбокса как я написал. А что бы его использовать сначала необходимо контрол скастить в текстбокс. Тогда сработает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> appendtext не подходит, так как задача именно в этом методе это поправить.

Почему не подходит? Прямо в этом методе и правьте.

```
if (ctrl is TextBoxBase tbx)
    tbx.AppendText(text);
else
    ctrl.Text += text;
```

Сработает и для ричбокса, и для тексбокса.

Вообще `+=` к тексту тексбокса - плохая практика. Это ужасно медленная операция.

*Еще я бы переименовал бы метод `SetText`. Если судить о методе по названию, то из него кажется, что этот метод заменяет текст в контроле, а не добавляет. Название `AddText` или `AppendText` было бы понятнее.*

Comment: За место += использовать лучше String.Concat ?

Comment: @arc_pd нет, того что я предложил - достаточно.